# os.system() leads to invalid console output of print() python function even under mutex

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, threadpool, os.system

I made a script which calls some program via `os.system()` inside a ThreadPool and prints results of work to console. Simplified code looks this way:

```
import os
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import multiprocessing
from threading import Lock

print_mutex = Lock()
def print_safe(text):
    with print_mutex:
        print(text, flush=True)

def print_smth():
    res = os.system("")
    print_safe("1")

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as thread_pool:
    future_results = [thread_pool.submit(print_smth) for i in range(40)]

    for future in future_results:
        future.result()
```

But in console output I receive unexpected result like that:

[image: Console output]

If I comment `res = os.system("")` call, then output becomes valid.

Why does os.system() influences such way on print function?

What is the correct way to implement process calls to avoid such issue?

Comment: Is you real (non-simplified) subprocess printing something?

Comment: I can't reproduce this with `os.system("")`.

Comment: I can reproduce indeed, on Windows

Comment: @o11c it doesn't matter. I tried both options in simplified example and got the same behavior. I ran example on python 3.8.2 on Windows 10 in cmd

Comment: @Barmar you can increase amount of calls from 40 to 100 or more

Comment: I ran it on MacOS. I tried increasing to 100, no change.

Comment: Is `os.system()` produces output, it won't be protected by the mutex.

Comment: The issue is reproducible even in case of ```os.system("")```, so no output from it.

Comment: Sounds like an issue specific to `os.system()` on Windows.

Comment: This seems command prompt specific. I can reproduce fairly frequently with `cmd.exe`, however, powershell, windows terminal, and vs code's terminal don't seem to suffer from the same problem. Even stranger is the fact that pasting the text anywhere else displays it as a `CRLF`.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening:

Threadpool creates a pool of threads that do work in parallel.  However, your main thread is still a single thread.  If you have a job that takes no time (less than the cycle of the loop calling a function itself) it will finish in the time it takes to call the next function, it will appear synchronous.

`os.system` is taking some sort of time on your pc (this can change depending on speed, OS, and number of CPU) so threads are ending simultaneously, and due to the delay for the work of calling `os.system` they are printing next to each other since they printed in the same single threaded cycle of the main app (the one printing to console).

If your function does actual work, you would see the results you were expecting.

Comment: So you suggest some workaround to hide the problem?

Comment: My suggestion is it is working as it should.  You should not rely on the print function to test async.  You should instead rely on complete operation time.